# Is it possible to read a text from blob type?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I have a **text file** which I am **saving in** Mysql as `BLOB` type. Is it possible to search that table using the text content in the saved text file?

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: What a Charset? There are thousands of Charsets. You need thousands of querys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your text file format, you could search like TEXT with BLOB if the content was not compressed. You could also create full-text index with BLOB. Beware comparison in BLOB is case-sensitive.